# ASP.NET multiview switches / jumps automatically to other page when pressing enter in a textfield

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

I have a MultiView with two Views, 
each View contains a Button that goes to the other view when clicked
 as the first element in the view and somewhere later one or more TextBoxes.
like:

```
<asp:Button ID="userConfSwitch" runat="server" Text="Configure Users" Width="128"
                OnClick="SwitchToUserConfig" />
            <br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Width="400px"></asp:TextBox>
```

in a View.

Now, whenever i press enter in the TextBox, the MultiView switches to the other View.
if i have another button at first, like:

```
<div style="display: none">
                <asp:Button runat="server" Text="seeing this is a bug" />
            </div>
```

that doesn't switch the View when clicked, nothing happens when i press enter.

What is causing this (a bug or a "feature") and how do i disable it without that hidden Button?

Answer (score 0):

You can change Button property "UseSubmitBehavior" to "false".